# Negative Binomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a negative binomial with parameters $r$ and $p$. So $X$ is the number of trials $k$ till the $r^{th}$ success.

My first question is determine which values of $k$ the ratio $\frac{P(X=k+1)}{P(X=k)}=\frac{k(1-p)}{k-r+1}$ will be greater than 1. Thus find the value of $k$ for which $P(K=k)$ will be the greatest.

I simply set that ratio to be greater than one and solved and got $k<\frac{(r-1)}{p}$. Is this correct? I do not know what that means though. Also is that the value of $k$ for which $P(K=k)$ will be the greatest? Because I have no idea what that part is even asking for in words, the greatest value question.

Lastly here is the question of how to apply it.

Suppose prob of writing to complain is .05. Someone calls people at random until they have 4 people that have written to complain. Use the above to find the most likely number of calls that the person had to make. How does this compare to the expected number of calls.

For the expected value part, I know the expected value of a negative binomial is $r/p$, which in this case is $4/.05$ if I am not mistaken. But I am lost on how to find the first part. Is it this:

$P(X=n)=$$(n-1)\choose(r-1)$$p^r*(1-p)^{n-r}$. Where r=4, p=.05, and we must find $n$? This is were I get a little lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your result of $k \lt \dfrac{r-1}{p}$ is correct. This means $P(X=k+1) \gt P(X=k)$ iff $k \lt \dfrac{r-1}{p}$.

You can think of $\{P(X=k+1)\}_{k=r-1}^{\infty}$ as a sequence in $k$ that is increasing whilever $k \lt \dfrac{r-1}{p}$ and thereafter is decreasing.

In turn, this means that $P(X=k+1)$ is maximised for the smallest $k$ such that $k \geq \dfrac{r-1}{p}$. In fact, if for that value of $k$ we have $k = \dfrac{r-1}{p}$, (which is to say $\dfrac{r-1}{p}$ is an integer) then $P(X=k+1) = P(X=k)$ and these are both the maximum probability value.

$\\$

When $p = 0.05,\; r=4,\;$ we require

$$k\geq \dfrac{4-1}{0.05} = 60.$$

Because $60$ is an integer, the values of $X$ with maximum probability are $60$ and $61$. These are both the most likely number of calls needed.

Your answer of $E(X) = 4/0.05 = 80$ is correct.

Comment: I see how you get 60, but that middle is still confusing. I get how it the sequence is increasing and the k part is decreasing, but I do not see it as a sequence. The whole maximizing for the smallest is also confusing. Because how is it $k\ge (r-1)/p$. then how could they both be the max prob value? I get 60 and 61 assuming the above is correct, but not the above part. thank you though, I was getting worried

Comment: @Jack Hi Jack. $P(X=k+1)/P(X=k)\gt 1$ is the same as $P(X=k+1)\gt P(X=k)$. (Just multiply both sides of the inequality by $P(X=k)$.) You found that this is the same as $k\lt (r-1)/p$. Now, the smallest $k$ is $r$, so this means we have $P(X=r)\lt P(X=r+1)\lt P(X=r+2)\lt\cdots\lt P(X=k_0)\geq P(X=k_0+1)\geq\cdots$ where $k_0$ is the first $k$ where $k\lt (r-1)/p$ is false. In the example, $k_0=60$. Because that value $k_0$ is the point at which the probabilities stop increasing and start decreasing instead, it must be the point at which the probability is maximised. I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: in all honesty, going from greater to less than or equal makes no sense. But is 60 the most likely number of calls. I see how it reaches the maximum and then must start to fall or else it would not be a max. But how can there be two answers for the most likely number of calls?

Comment: @Jack Perhaps you could calculate $P(X=60)$ and $P(X=61)$ and check that they are equal? If so, then $60$ and $61$ can both be the answer.

Comment: yea your right mathematically. I just cant wrap my head around it. I just now have to figure out the inequalities. So that value of $P(X=k_0)$ is the value of $k$ for which $P(K=k)$ is the greatest because since the smallest $k$ is $r$, we have ... your inequalitiy.. where $k<(r-1)/p$ is false.